# How to retrieve data from a file (specifically a model in Django) located on another branch on github on the current branch?

Tags: django, github, branch

I need help working with github - I'm working on a project in Django REST and I've created a new branch that contains a segment of the project. Since I need a Django model that is part of another branch (but also on the master branch because that branch is merged with master), I'm wondering how I can get it to use it on this current branch that I need it on as well?

Since it is also a SQL table, I need that model to be the same wherever I use it, I will only possibly take new data.

Thank you in advance!